# Java Object to save timestamp in mongo db using jongo?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to save timestamp information in mongodb.

I would like to know equivalent time stamp class which needs to be used in the entity to save it via jongo.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

java.util.Date works well for me.

Comment: how about using java.util.Timestamp

Comment: Add a new field/s for timestamps to the MongoDB collection and add the object of java.util.Date to it. That is the simplest thing that I do.